# Windows App PushPlugin issue in ionic framework

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, plugins, ionic-framework

I am working on Hybrid App(ionic platform) for windows device.
Previously i was working on same app in jqm(java query mobile),Now i am using ionic framework for same app.I was using a plugin for Push notification in windows phone.While i am using same plugin into ionic framework and its not working it is giving me an error:

ERROR: Exception in InvokeScriptCallback :: An unknown error has occurred. Error: 80020101.

Plugin calls the register function for push notification registration but in call back function it got crash with above given error.
Does any body have any idea.Please help,Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using PushPlugin, there is a bug report here: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/500 where the suggestion is: Make sure your date and time settings are correct on your virtual or physical device.

Comment: I have checked, my device's time and date settings are correct.and in this article they are at least getting callback to their uri function but in my case i am not receiving call to uri function ie,It got crash while call from push plugin class to cordova java script class.Thanks for your response :)

Comment: check the cordova version compatibility with the plugin. Sometimes this might cause the issue too.

Comment: i have not updated cordova version and it is working fine for JQM App on same system :(

Comment: Here is a discussion on this topic please check this: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/500